# Startup Script Launch IE Browser

Tags: group-policy, startup-scripts

how to launch a startup script (batch file or VBS or PowerShell) that will open a browser on startup?

I want to deploy this using GPO, i'm only able to achieve this by using logon script, but if used the script on startup it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas how to launch a browser on computer startup using GPO?

Thank you for any input. :)

Comment: At computer startup, no one has logged on to the computer yet, so on who's logon session do you expect the browser to run?

Comment: okay, so basically its not possible to initialize the browser via script and run it on startup? or do something like runas user_profile?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the computer to boot, logon, and start a browser your best bet is a combination of the [`AutoAdminLogon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939702.aspx) functionality and your already-working logon script.

Plug: [I wrote an Administrative Template for Group Policy](https://serverfault.com/a/265063/7200) for AutoAdminLogon. This makes applying this setting to machines via Group Policy very handy, albeit it's not a "real" policy setting so it does "tattoo" the registry (necessitating the creation of an "evil anti-policy" to reverse it).